# Delphi 7 and Windows Vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista

I have a simple software that is made in Delphi 7, and it crashes on Vista after a while.  These are totally random crashes, nothing is written in any crash log, just stops working and then Vista tries to find a solution.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried it on one machine or on several machines with Vista installed.
What kind of application are you running? Singe *.exe, bound external DLL's, database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one of the exception catchers, like madExcept. It can often help you find out what is happening inside your app at the time of trouble. In general though Delphi apps are fine in Vista, so there must be some interaction, perhaps user rights, that is causing trouble.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

- DEP - try disabling DEP for the program an see if it solves the problem
- ASLR
- It fails to get access to some resource, gets a NULL pointer (a common way of functions to signal that they failed) and tries to use that (with predictable results)

The best thing would be to run with a debugger (preferably Delphi 7 - it sounds like you have source code) attached and check the exact location of the crash.

Comment: ASLR is not enabled by default, until you explictly ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

just to point out--madExcept has a "hang" detection option that should help.